# Specify the input method for a file

Tags: input-method, file-local-variables

Using Doom Emacs 2.0.9 on Emacs 26.3 on Manjaro.

I am writing some devanagari text in a file.

Every time I edit the file, I need to `toggle-input-method` and select 'devanagari'.

Is there a way to specify the 'default' input method for a file? I will then use `toggle-input-method` to switch back to normal input method, English.

Comment: StackOverflow has a duplicate Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45893232/how-to-set-a-specific-input-method-to-a-file

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been asked and answered on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @phils AFAIK Postings on different sites (including sites from the SE-network) are no duplicates. I think the right way is to write an answer with a reference to the SO posting and a quote of it (in the case the answer is deleted on the other site).

Comment: I disagree (pretty strongly) with that approach.  To my mind, the S.E. ideal is that there is *one* definitive answer to a given question.  Having multiple Q&As only leads to splintering of the answers across the sites, and consequently reduces their visibility.  If I copy the answer here, and someone then posts a better answer here instead of to the original Q&A, then some people won't find that better answer.  Better to close this Q&A and direct users to a single place.

Comment: I don't think the "in the case the answer is deleted on the other site" scenario is worth considering -- S.O. is part of the same network, is one of the valid places on that network to ask Emacs questions, and contains a vast collection of those questions.  I'm only as concerned about those Q&As being deleted as I am about the ones here being deleted.  I certainly don't think it's worth creating the practical problem of splintered answers on account of the theoretical problem of valid Q&As elsewhere on the network being deleted.

Comment: Hi, @phils. I understand your concerns. There are several [ways to deal with cross-site duplicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4708/what-to-do-with-cross-site-duplicates/325934#325934). I think this question is not primarily about programming. So perhaps the version from SO should be moved to here and then this question could be marked as duplicate on the same site.

Comment: As the S.O. question is valid (Emacs questions have always been on-topic there -- questions about programmer tools do not need to be directly about programming), I suggest we instead migrate this question to S.O. and close it as a duplicate.  Otherwise the inference is that every time someone asks a question on E.S. which was already answered on S.O. that the original Q&A should be moved, and I don't think that's right.  Actually being able to mark cross-site duplicates would be the best solution -- I feel the linked meta discussion makes that pretty clear; I'm not sure why it hasn't happened.